# Combinatorics for a lattice with multiple gas types

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

Let there be a lattice with $N$ sites, corresponding to the number of gas molecules in the system. There are $n_0$ molecules with energy $e_0$, $n_1$ molecules with energy $e_1$, $n_N$ molecules with energy $e_N$. How do I calculate the total amount of microstates?

My textbook says:

$W = N! /(n_0!n_1!n_2!...)$

However, I am not able to justify this result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that expression for W should be a multiple of some combination. If you write it out you'll see that the (n-r)! and N! terms cancel:

For the case of N particles, with species Na, Nb, Nc:

W = (N choose Na)⋅(N-Na choose Nb)⋅(N-Na-Nb choose Nc)⋅...

W = N!/(Na!Nb!Nc!...)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @anno Since this is a Q&A site, answers are expected to be detailed. A post like yours should be posted as a comment, not as an answer (unless you give additional details).